# Как поменять несколько бит в картинке bmp в с++

Tags: c++, binary, bmp

уважаемые знатоки. Возникла задача - записать в файл (картинку .bmp) некий текст. Текст нужно взять из файла и записать в существующую картинку. Я погуглил, и решил, что нужно открывать файл-картинку в двоичном виде, но проблема в том, что я не могу понять, как считывать эти самые биты. У меня получается всякая абра кадабра. Так вот вопрос, что нужно сделать, чтобы записать в конец каждого байта некоторый символ в виде его числового представления пока сообщение не кончится?
Я написал такой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string data = "I:\\NumMet\\bmp\\data.txt";
    string image = "I:\\NumMet\\bmp\\bmp.bmp";
    string message = "";
    ifstream fin(data);
    ifstream fin2(image, ios::binary);

    if (!fin.is_open() && !fin2.is_open()) {
        cout << "File not open";
        return 0;
    }

    // считываю текст для записи в картинку
    char ch;
    int count = 0;
    while (fin.get(ch)) {
        message += ch;
        count++;
    }
    cout << count << ' ';
    cout << message;
    fin.close();

    // скипаю байты на всякий случай
    int i = 0;
    fin2.seekg(256);

    // проверяю, что достаточно пикселей для записи
    i = 0;
    while (fin2.get(ch) && i < count) {
        i++;
    }
    if (i < count) {
        cout << "picture is small";
    }
    else {
        cout << "Good";
        // замена битов картинки на биты символов.
    }
    fin2.close();
}
```

В нем я считываю сообщения для записи, пропускаю несколько байт, чтобы не задеть системные данные (но я не нашел, сколько именно надо пропускать, потому взял с запасом) и после проверки, что пикселей для записи хватит - должен записывать те самые данные.

Добавлено: Загрузил картинку  с результатом работы программы[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Вообще-то bmp — это не просто так, а имеет определенную структуру - заголовок, данные... Да и что надо, непонятно - записать текст *как*? Чтобы его можно было прочесть на картинке глазами, так сказать?...

Comment: Я знаю, что там есть структура, но ума разобраться не хватило, вот и сделал с запасом отступ. А текс в виде кодов записать. То-есть считать пиксель (2 байта, как я понял) И записать в этот пиксель код символа. Чтобы все символы тектса были записаны в пиксель. Я полагаю, это надо записывать в последние биты. Думаю, 5 бит в конце должно хватить на английский алфавит, но лучше взять 6 бит, для верности. Но как считать, модифицировать и перезаписать пиксель - не понятно.

Comment: Структура BMP-файла [достаточно проста](http://www.ece.ualberta.ca/~elliott/ee552/studentAppNotes/2003_w/misc/bmp_file_format/bmp_file_format.htm). В заголовке есть вся необходимая информация. Если изображение имеет глубину цвета > 8 бит, то таблица цветов отсутствует, а значит через 54 байта располагаются пиксели. Для 24-битного изображения каждые 3 байта задают цвет пикселя (RGB). Каждая строка должна быть кратна 4 и дополняется нулевыми байтами, при необходимости. Открываете файл для чтения и записи. Далее, чтение, побитовые операции, запись.

Comment: Чтобы иметь минимальное воздействие на изображение, лучше распределить 5-ти битовый код символа по компонентам (2+2+1) и записывать в младшие биты.
Если Вам вообще не важно, куда писать, то отступаете до пикселей, читаете байт, заменяете в нём 5 младших бит: `a & (255 << 5) | b`, записываете.

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение. Я в вики нашел, что обычно размер заголовка = 54 байтам. Также я погуглил и нашел инфу о том, что для минимизации изменений в картинке нужно кодировать символ порциями, но я все еще не понимаю, как считывать и записывать данные из/в бинарный файл. Я считывал весь файл в цикле и выводил содержимое, и это были либо набор длинных цифр, либо набор невнятных символов. Если есть возможность привести пример кода для считывания/изменения бит в байте, буду крайне признателен.

Comment: Я так понял, вы реализуете [стеганографию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Стеганография). Гляньте [это](https://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-builder/thread103448.html).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Вторая ссылка любопытная. Автор темы подчёркивает, что отсчёт бит идёт справа налево, при этом, меняя младший бит с 1 на 0, комментирует, что «теперь R = 127». Или я что-то не учёл?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я рассмотрю вариант, когда алфавит кодируется пятью битами и в каждом байте пиксельных данных мы меняем 1 младший бит. Таким образом, для одного символа потребуется пять байт. Это вариант с наименьшим воздействием на изображение.

Имеем 26 букв латинского алфавита + пробел. Еще в запасе 5 кодов.

Если внимательно посмотреть на [структуру](http://www.ece.ualberta.ca/%7Eelliott/ee552/studentAppNotes/2003_w/misc/bmp_file_format/bmp_file_format.htm), то мы увидим, что по адресу 0x0a можно прочитать смещение пиксельных данных от начала файла.

Записать данные не проблема, а вот как при чтении понять, какое количество символов нужно прочитать и есть ли этот текст вообще? Можно использовать пару из неиспользуемых кодов в алфавите в качестве терминальных символов (начало и конец строки). Но вероятность ложного захвата строки все же остается, хоть и сводится к минимуму при желании.

Я же обратил внимание на то, что есть неиспользуемые 4 байта по адресу 0x06, куда можно записать размер строки.

Дальнейшие комментарии в коде. Лишних проверок не делаю.

**Запись данных**

```cpp
// Открываем файлы. BMP на чтение и запись
fstream fImg(image, ios::binary | ios::in | ios::out);
ifstream fTxt(text);

char ch;
unsigned char byte;
long offset;
long count = 0;

// Считываем смещение пиксельных данных
fImg.seekg(0x0a);
fImg.read((char*)&offset, 4);

while (fTxt.get(ch)) {

    // алфавит начинается с ASCII кода 97, нам нужно с 0
    ch -= 97;

    // все что не входит в 5 бит, будет под кодом 31 (в дальнейшем пробел)
    if (ch < 0 || ch > 31) ch = 31;

    // итерируем 5 бит символа
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++, offset++)
    {
        // значение младшего бита
        int firstBit = ch & 1;

        // читаем байт пиксельных данных
        fImg.seekg(offset);
        byte = fImg.peek();

        // Заменяем младший бит на firstBit символа
        byte ^= (-firstBit ^ byte) & 1U;

        // записываем байт обратно
        fImg.seekp(offset);
        fImg.put(byte);

        // побитовый сдвиг вправо, чтобы получить следующий младший бит
        ch >>= 1;
    }

    // кол-во записанных символов
    count++;
}

// Записываем в неиспользуемое поле заголовка длину строки
fImg.seekp(0x06);
fImg.write((const char*)&count, sizeof(count));

fTxt.close();
fImg.close();
```

**Чтение**

```cpp
ifstream fImg(image);

char ch;
unsigned char byte;
long count;
long offset;

// Считываем длину строки
fImg.seekg(0x06);
fImg.read((char*)&count, 4);

// Считываем смещение пиксельных данных
fImg.seekg(0x0a);
fImg.read((char*)&offset, 4);

while (count--) {

    ch = 0;

    // нужно 5 байт, чтобы восстановить символ
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++, offset++)
    {
        // читаем байт
        fImg.seekg(offset);
        byte = fImg.peek();

        // получаем младший бит
        int firstBit = byte & 1;

        // заменяем i-тый бит на firstBit
        ch ^= (-firstBit ^ ch) & (1U << i);
    }

    // Все, что не буква, будет пробел
    if (ch > 25) ch = -65;
    ch += 97;

    cout << ch;
}

fImg.close();
```

**Дополнение**
Код работает для 24-битных изображений и 8-битных с равномерной grayscale-палитрой.

Comment: Код рабочий, но на картинке с белый фоном четко видно синие точки. Я полагаю, нужно записывать не в последние биты, а в конец каждого байта, отвечающего за цвет. К сожалению, я не понимаю, как работать с бинарными файлами и не знаю, как сделать запись символа, к примеру, в последние 2 бита каждого цветового байта пикселя. Так можно будет зашифровать символ с меньшим влиянием на картинку. Можете написать, как это сделать? В любом случае, спасибо за ваш ответ, он мне очень помог.

Comment: @Андрей Так и происходит, запись производится в конец каждого байта (в последний, младший бит). Я даже на белой картинке не могу увидеть разницу. Приложите изображение к вопросу, проверю. Ещё раз, речь не идёт о нескольких битах, я меняю только последний бит каждого байта.

Comment: Я добавил картинку. Судя по всему, запись происходит только в байт, отвечающий за красный цвет, так как коды других цветов не изменились в каждом пикселе.

Comment: @Андрей Вы используете 8-битное изображение. В этом случае, в файл записывается палитра из 256 цветов, а байты в пиксельных данных ссылаются на цвета в палитре. Paint при сохранении 8-bit картинки записывает в файл стандартную палитру. Под индексом 255 - белый цвет, а под индексом 254 - (0, 255, 255) - цвет морской волны, который вы и видите. Механизм ясный, если обнулить у значения 255 младший бит, получим 254. Если бы палитра содержала оттенки серого (так можно сохранить в других редакторах), то проблемы бы не было. **Вывод: используйте 24-битное изображение или 8-ми с grayscale палитрой.**

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо. Я все еще не понимаю, как работать с бинарными файлами, но я более-менее разобрался с форматом бмп и получил интересный опыт.